# Sublime open file hotkey

Tags: file, hotkeys

I know that I can use 'Ctrl + p' to find file and open it. But it search file in all projects. What is the way to search file only in current project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Ctrl`+`P` key binding opens what is known as "GoTo Anything". The [Sublime Text Unofficial Documentation on GoTo Anything](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#goto-anything) states (emphasis added):

> As you type into Goto Anything’s input area, **names of files in the current project will be searched**, and a preview of the best match will be shown.

Further down [in the documentation in the "Sidebar" section](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#sidebar) it states:

> **The sidebar provides an overview of the active project** (more on projects later). **Files and folders in the sidebar will be available in Goto Anything** and project-wide actions like, for example, project-wide searches.
>
> Projects and the sidebar are closely related. **It’s important to note that there’s always an active project, whether it’s explicit or implicit.**

I would bet that your current active Sublime project includes files which should be moved to a separate (explicit) project and that is why they are being included in the search results contrary to your desire. To learn more about projects, read even further down in the documentation in [the section titled "Projects"](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#projects).

Comment: Thanks. Now i understand that there is difference between folders and projects. I created a new project and added a needed folder to it. So now I enjoy 'Ctrl + p' hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this one: `Shift+Command+F`, then you can enter search keyword as follows:
[image]

> Find: Please enter search keyword
>
> Where: Select the project location

Comment: It search words, not files